# How to sort a vector of structure belonging to same category/set in c++

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stl

While solving a competitive coding problem I got stuck with the the following sorting scenario.
I have a vector of following structure

```
struct Data{
    int p;
    int val;
    int ll;
};
```

Defined as :

```
vector<Data> a(N);
```

Now p field in the structure tells the set number to which val belong.
e.g if values are 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
(1,4,7) belong to group/set 3 i.e p is 3  , (2,5,8) belong to group/set 4 i.e p is 4 and (3,6,9) belong to group/set 5 i.e p is 5

i have p and val field in structure as
p as 3 4 5 3 4 5 3 4 5
val as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Now the problem is I have to sort the vector set wise in descending order 
i.e 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
here 1 4 and 7 belong to set 3 so they are sorted in their respective places.

I tried with the selection sort as below which worked fine but it gave Time limit exceeded because of O(N^2) complexity.

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    int mi=i;
    Data max=a[i];
    for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
    {
        if((a[i].p==a[j].p)&&(a[j].val>max.val))
        {
            max=a[j];
            mi=j;
        }
    }
    a[mi]=a[i];
    a[i]=max;
}
```

Please help me find the best (time complexity) way to sort this scenario (if possible using STL sort).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I tried with the bubble sort as below which worked fine but it gave Time limit exceeded because of O(N^2) complexity."* So this is part of an assignment/challenge? If it's an online challenge, please add a link, since your "sort vector set wise" description is rather confusing.

Comment: problem link is http://codeforces.com/contest/691/problem/D

Comment: @Zeta for clarity please check the example i have tried to explain and the final output

Comment: The examples and your description don't add up, that's why I've asked for the original assignment. Also, the values could be formatted a lot better.

Comment: may be i could not explain it properly because of editing ..please edit accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Modifying http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/, the key bit is:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

bool mycomparison (Data i, Data j) {
    if (i.p != j.p)
        return j.p < i.p;
    else
        return j.val < i.val;
}

...

// Sort vector a
a.std::sort( a.begin(), a.end(), mycomparison );

...
```

Note that reversing `i` and `j` in the `return` lines causes things to be in descending order.

Comment: u have misunderstood my problem. its not that type of sorting. i need to sort val corresponding to same value of p . that is value of p forms a set and each val should be sorted setwise

Comment: @monkey Your description was rather unclear.  But if you sort by p and then by val, after that you can easily break it up by value of p.